# why server is required for running swt application in Scout

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap, eclipse-scout

I am new to eclipse scout. I create my first scount hello world application for swt . It automatically created
the server project as well. But when I try to run the swt application, I got the error saying that server
has to start first. Why does server has to run in order to swt client application? Request you to explain the 
concept of server here.

Comment: My understanding of Scout is that it's a client-server platform for building biz apps. It maybe that the framework simply doesn't support the concept of a standalone SWT app.

Comment: This has just been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655217/undeclaredthrowableexception-with-a-client-only-eclipse-scout-application

Answer (score 0):

RAP is an acronym for Remote Application Platform--the server needs to run for there to *be* a Remote.

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-box, scout applications are designed to be client-server applications. The architecture looks like this:

[image: architecture of eclipse scout application]

Your application is the blue part. As developer you focus on your business logic and you rely on the scout framework (orange part) and on the eclipse/equinox stack for common features. Eclipse Scout provides a client server communication mechanism (read more on the [architecture of Scout on the eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts))

Because typical applications look like this, `Scout SDK` makes the assumption that you want to create a client-server application. When you create a new scout project the client code contains code that induces a server call. If this is not your intention, it is possible to create a [client only application with eclipse scout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655217/undeclaredthrowableexception-with-a-client-only-eclipse-scout-application).