# UndeclaredThrowableException with a client only eclipse scout application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-scout

I am trying to do a client only Eclipse Scout application.

I selected the menu “New Scout Project…” and in the first step of the wizard I checked only:

- com.company.app.ui.swt
- com.company.app.client
- com.company.app.shared

Everything seems to be fine, but when I start my client application, I get following Stacktrace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.scout.rt.client 4 0 2014-07-09 15:35:06.078
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.AbstractClientSession.startSession(AbstractClientSession.java:257) load session
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.getAllCodeTypeClasses(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.code.CodeServiceClientProxy.getAllCodeTypeClasses(CodeServiceClientProxy.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.code.CodeServiceClientProxy.getAllCodeTypes(CodeServiceClientProxy.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.services.common.code.CODES.getAllCodeTypes(CODES.java:97)
    at com.company.app.client.ClientSession.execLoadSession(ClientSession.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.AbstractClientSession.startSession(AbstractClientSession.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.session.internal.ClientSessionRegistryService$1.runVoid(ClientSessionRegistryService.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ClientJob.runStatus(ClientJob.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ClientJob.runTransactionWrapper(ClientJob.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ClientJob.run(ClientJob.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.scout.commons.job.JobEx.runNow(JobEx.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.session.internal.ClientSessionRegistryService.createAndStartClientSession(ClientSessionRegistryService.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.session.internal.ClientSessionRegistryService.newClientSession(ClientSessionRegistryService.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.swt.AbstractSwtEnvironment$4.run(AbstractSwtEnvironment.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Why does the Client application needs to connect to a server that do not exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of the `Scout SDK`.

When you create your new scout project, the generated client code rely on a server, even if you have unchecked the server in the wizard.

You need to remove the elements that produce calls to the server.

In `<your app>.client.ClientSession.execLoadSession()` remove the lines:

```
setServiceTunnel(new ClientHttpServiceTunnel(this, UriUtility.toUrl(getBundle().getBundleContext().getProperty("server.url"))));

//pre-load all known code types
CODES.getAllCodeTypes(com.company.app.shared.Activator.PLUGIN_ID);
```

In `<your app>.client.ui.desktop.Desktop` remove the inner-class:

```
@Order(25)
public class BookmarkMenu extends AbstractBookmarkMenu {
  public BookmarkMenu() {
    super(Desktop.this);
  }
}
```

Your client only application will start.

Answer (score 0):

The new project wizard of the `Scout SDK` is not really suitable to create a client only application. You need to adapt the generated code manually in some places.

The simplest (and most limited) approach is described in the [Scout book](http://tools.bsiag.com/scoutbook/4.0/2014-05-30_01-05-57/html/bookch11.html#x94-13400010.2) where we describe a Scout widget demo application.

For a more elaborate answer you might want to read through this [forum post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/210183/).