# Eclipse Scout RAP UI deployment in Websphere

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, websphere, eclipse-scout

Am new to Eclipse, we are trying to deploy a 'hello world' code in WebSphere 8.5.
We were able to export and deploy the **Server & RAP** Web application (Test.ear).
but when we try to access the URL (https://host:32121/Test/web), Scout loads but it throws "Server Not Found (ConnectException Connection Refused), Please check server Name, URL and server connection".

We need to access RAP UI page of Eclipse(Luna SR2), hosted in WebSphere.

Comment: Do not hesitate the continue the discussion if my answer did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the Stacktrace, I can only guess…

In a typical Eclipse Scout application, you have a client and a server application. When the RAP-UI is used, the “scout client” is also a server (the RAP Server). My guess is that you have deployed the RAP server but that it still tries to connect to the Scout Server (and this is the exception you see).

If you want to have only the RAP server (== Scout Client) without Scout Server, check how to create [a scout client only application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655217/undeclaredthrowableexception-with-a-client-only-eclipse-scout-application).

Comment: Thank you Jmini, I will check and revert with results.